# Why won't my jquery ajax request work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am super new to jquery and ajax, so please excuse me. Anyways, I am trying to send a location to the google geocoding api and receive back a pair of coordinates. However, for some reason my function won't work. What am I doing wrong and how should i fix it?

Scripts.js

```
function getData(address)
{
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      'address': address,
      'api'    : 
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var results = data.results;
        localStorage.setItem("hi",data.results);
        alert(results);
        return results;
    }
  });   


}

function getAddress()
{
    var address = document.getElementById('aa').value;
    console.log(address);
    localStorage.setItem("add", address);
    window.location="weather.html";
    var array = getData(localStorage.add);
    console.log("hi");
}
if(window.location.pathname == "/home.html"){
    document.getElementById("swag").onclick = getAddress
 } 

if(localStorage.add && window.location.pathname != "/weather.html"){
    window.location="weather.html";
}
```

Comment: 1. Open developers console.

Comment: Is that your API key? Please remove it from plain sight! Also, it should be sent as a string, enclosed in single or double quotes.

Comment: I did, but the issue is, I can't see the error because It blinks and goes away :/

Comment: try adding an error handler in your ajax call and see what the error is returned from the server if the call is made.

Comment: Cans someone please help me???